# How to run tracks from different components?

Tags: reactjs, api, user-interface, tailwind-css, spotify-app

Hi I am trying to play music from different `react` `components`.

I have main component called **Dashboard**, where other components(search bar, table with top artists, player etc...)

```
function Dashboard({ accessToken }) {
    const [searchKey, setSearchKey] = useState('');
    const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([]);
    const [selectedTrack, setSelectedTrack] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [selectedTopTrack, setSelectedTopTrack] = useState(null);

    const handleSelectTopTrack = (track) => {
        setSelectedTopTrack(track);
      
    };

    const searchTracks = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTracks([]);
        setIsLoading(true);
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
            params: {
                q: searchKey,
                type: 'track',
            },
        });
        const tracks = data.tracks.items.map((item) => {
            return {
                artist: item.artists[0].name,
                title: item.name,
                uri: item.uri,
                albumUrl: item.album.images[0].url,
            };
        });
        setTracks(tracks);
        setIsLoading(false);
    };



    const renderTracks = () => {
        return tracks.map((track) => (
            <TrackSearchResult
                key={track.uri}
                track={track}
                chooseTrack={setSelectedTrack}
                albumUrl={track.albumUrl}
            />
        ));
    };

    return (
        <div className="w-full min-h-screen flex flex-col justify-items-center items-center overflow-y-scroll">
            {accessToken ? (
                <div className="ml-8 flex flex-col w-full">
                    <h1 className="font-semibold text-xl md:text-2xl">Unleash Your Rhythm</h1>
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setSearchKey(e.target.value)} />
                        <button type="button" onClick={searchTracks}>Search</button>
                    </form>
                    {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                    {renderTracks()}
                    <TopArtist accessToken={accessToken} />
                    <h2>Popular</h2>
                    <TableArtist accessToken={accessToken} onSelectTopTrack={handleSelectTopTrack} />
                    <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0  w-full">
                        <SpotifyPlayer play={true} className="w-full" token={accessToken} uris={[selectedTrack, selectedTopTrack]} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <Login />
            )}
        </div>

    );
```

And here I have table filled tracks from TOP 50 playlist.

```
function TableArtist({ accessToken, onSelectTopTrack }) {
    const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([]);


    const handleTrackSelect = (trackId) => {
        getTrackUri(trackId);

    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!accessToken) return alert("Failed OAUTH");

        axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF/tracks?fields=items(track(name%2C%20id)%2C%20track(album(images)%2C%20artists))', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
        }).then(response => {
            setTracks(response.data.items);
            
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }, [accessToken]);

    const getTrackUri = (trackId) => {
        if (!accessToken) return alert("Failed OAUTH");

        axios.get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${trackId}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
        })
            .then(response => {
                const trackUri = response.data.uri;
                onSelectTopTrack(trackUri);
                
                
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <section className="container mr-4 mb-4 mt-4 md:mr-8 md:mb-8 md:mt-8">
            <div className="w-full mb-8 overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg ">
                <div className="w-full ">
                    <table className="w-full  ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr className="text-md font-semibold tracking-wide text-left text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 uppercase border-b border-gray-600">
                                <th className="px-4 py-3">ID</th>
                                <th className="px-4 py-3">Name</th>
                                <th className="px-4 py-3">Album</th>
                                <th className="px-4 py-3">Artist</th>
                                <th className="px-4 py-3">Added</th>
                                <th className="px-4 py-3"><BiTimeFive /></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody className="bg-white">
                            {tracks.map((track, index) => (
                                
                                <tr key={index} className="text-gray-700" onClick={() => handleTrackSelect(track.track.id)}>
                                    <td className = "px-4 py-3 text-ms font-semibold border" >{index}</td>
                                    <td className="px-4 py-3 border">
                                        <div className="flex items-center text-sm">
                                            <div class="relative w-8 h-8 mr-3 rounded-full md:block">
                                                <img className="object-cover w-full h-full " src={track.track.album.images[0].url} alt="" loading="lazy" /> 
                                                <div className="absolute inset-0 rounded-full shadow-inner" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <p className="font-semibold text-black">{ track.track.name}</p> 
                                                <p className="text-xs text-gray-600">{track.track.artists[0].name }</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>

                                    <td className="px-4 py-3 text-ms font-semibold border">{track.track.album.name}</td>
                                    <td className="px-4 py-3 text-ms font-semibold border">{track.track.artists[0].name}</td>
                                    <td className="px-4 py-3 text-ms font-semibold border">08/04/2023</td>
                                    <td className="px-4 py-3 text-ms font-semibold border">4:21</td>





                                </tr>

                            ))}
                           
                          
                           
                          
                           
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    );
```

My problem is I am able to play tracks only from single component(if I remove one of them), I want to let user play tracks both from the table and from the search engine.

```
<SpotifyPlayer play={true} className="w-full" token={accessToken} uris={[selectedTrack, selectedTopTrack]} />
```